# postgresql 9.3 ident authentication failed for user

Tags: postgresql, yii2, centos7

Unable to log into postgresql through yii2 migrate script.  Running on centos 7

the fatal error is always

```
Error:  SQLSTATE(08006) [7] FATAL:   Ident authentication failed for user "username"
```

I've changed the pg_hba.conf no longer has ident in it for authentication.  but its still trying to run against ident instead of trust, password or md5 (tried all of them)

I'm guessing that for some reason its not reading the pg_hba.conf file, i've manually added the full path to it in postgresql.conf but still says ident authentication failed.

pg_hba.conf contains

```
local   all             all                                     password
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            password
host    all             all             ::1/128                 password
```

i can log in from the command line no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start the service by using systemctl start postgresql-9.3 but stopping and restarting was not reloading the data.  I had to restart the server to get it to reload the data.

first try

```
systemctl stop postgresql-9.3
systemctl start postgresql-9.3
```

if that doesn't work, restart your machine